# Why does the recycle bin have a size limit?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

What is the reason we can/should limit the size of the recycle bin in Windows? Why not just make it unlimited, and empty it when you feel like it? (I know we can customize the size, but don't see why).

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. There **IS** a reason why you can set the limit. It's not like the guys at Microsoft were like *"oh boy we should allow the user to put a size limit 'cuz yeaaaaaaaaaahhhhh!"*.

Answer (score 6):

Because it needs to guarentee (to a degree) that it can save your files. Let's work with a 20GB partition, and use 10% as an example. You can delete up to 2GB worth of files, and it will ensure you can still access it.

Now, I want to "recycle" a 4GB file. It's too big, so it gets removed immediately. Why? Because the Recycling Bin is not so important that it should leak out on other parts of your disk. If the Recycling Bin gets too full, it has been known to delete older data automatically (TODO: Insert citation).

If you run a restaurant, you have MAYBE up to 1% of your floor space reserved for the garbage can - Your eggshells, your packaging, your dishwasher's cigarette box... Whatever you need to throw out. It keeps it separate from everything else, and prevents a mess. However, if you need to put more than 1% of your floor space *into* this garbage can, it's going to overflow and get messy. The point of the garbage can is to keep your kitchen clean. If you increased the size to 50%, then you'd have half garbage, half everything else. This would affect the quality of the food, and the staff, having too much garbage kicking around.

You can easily create a Garbage Can folder, and drop stuff in there, to later be deleted. There is no issue with that! However, you won't have the functionality of the Recycling Bin (i.e. can't execute files that have been recycled, meta data about where the file/folder belonged before, who the owner was, deleting with the keyboard or right-clicking and choosing Delete, etc). It will be up to you to decide if the trade off is worth it or not.

Comment: Downvoters, what do you find wrong with this answer? How can I improve it?